# Constant sectional curvature and the Riemann tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I am trying to prove the theorem that:

*Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian $n$-manifold of constant sectional curvature $C$. Then the curvature tensor is $R(X,Y)Z=C( \langle Y,Z \rangle X - \langle X, Z \rangle Y)$.*

I can show by straight-forward calculation (using the definition of sectional curvature) that *if* the curvature tensor is as stated, then $M$ has constant sectional curvature.

But the other way around is giving me some trouble. Does anybody have a hint?

Comment: Do you know the uniqueness property of curvature tensor?? Use that to prove the opposite direction.

Comment: No, I am not familiar with that? Can you by any chance provide me with some reference to that? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Look at the book Riemannian Geometry by Do Carmo...in the chapter of curvature you'll find this concept. Or rather try to solve it as an exercise.